# How to correct map this domain object in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

In database I have article and sets. Set contains some articles. 
Here is the example structure of sets in database:

```
 SetID | ArticleID | Count  
 #1    |  #2       |   1 
 #1    |  #3       |   2
```

Set with id: #1 contains 2 articles with id #2 and #3. 
My domains object looks like that:

```
class Set
{
  ... 
  ICollection<SetComponent> Components {get; set;}
}

class SetComponent 
{ 
   Article Article {get;set;}
   int Amount {get;set;}
}
```

How to map this to database with nHibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

```
class SetComponent 
{ 
    public virtual Set ContainingSet { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
    public virtual int Amount { get; set; }
}

public SetComponentMap()
{ 
    CompositeId()
        .KeyReference(x => x.ContainingSet, "SetID")
        .KeyReference(x => x.Article, "ArticleID");

    Map(x => x.Amount, "Count");
}

long setId = 5;
var components = session.Query<SetComponent>().Where(c => c.ContainingSet.Id == setId);
var set = new Set(setId, components);
```

**Option 2:**

```
class Set
{ 
    public virtual long Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual IList<SetComponent> Components { get; private set; }
}
class SetComponent 
{ 
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
    public virtual int Amount { get; set; }
}

public SetMap()
{ 
    Table("Sets");
    Id(x => x.Id, "SetId");

    // not pretty but has to be there to only return 1 row per id
    Where("ArticleID = (SELECT MIN(s.ArticleID) FROM Sets s WHERE s.SetId == SetId)");

    HasMany(x => x.Components)
        .Table("Sets")
        .KeyColumn("SetId")
        .Component(c =>
        {
            c.Reference(x => x.Article, "ArticleID");
            c.Map(x => x.Amount, "Count");
        });
}
```

Comment: thanks, for your answer. I've tried with option 2 but unfortunatelly it doesn't worked. I think that database schema is problematic here, my altertative solution was to use database query to get data and map result to classes. But this won't be entity then and I will have to write on myself methods to insert, delete data in my Repository class.

Comment: what means "doesn't work": Exception, other table structure something else?

Comment: Yes, it throws Exception, when session factory is being build. I think that problem is with that 'SetId' column. In my example I showed that there be more than one record with same setId, this isn't unique field.